# 535 Authentication Failed - Twilio SendGrid SMTP Relay NodeJS

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, nodemailer

I have a verified mail with Twilio SendGrid. I'm following the SMTP Relay stat up guide [here](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/smtp). I can't get it to send email using their SMTP Relay and NodeMailer. I need to know what I'm doing wrong?

In the example, they create an API Key and a password for you.

I'm using nodemailer here :

```
//smtp
smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
//secure: true,
port: 587,
auth: {
user: sendgrid_api_key, // generated ethereal user
pass: sendgrid_pass, // generated ethereal password
},
}));
```

When I run this I get error in the console :

> Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username /
> password
> at SMTPConnection._formatError

Answer (score 0):

When using SMTP to send emails with SendGrid, the username you should use is the string `apikey`. Then the password should be your actual API key that has permission to send emails.

Comment: Do you mean that we have two different API keys? In the startup guide they tell us to use the api_key as password?

Comment: I’m saying that the username should be the string “apikey”. You only need one generated API key from the SendGrid console and that goes as the password.

Comment: Okay. But it doesn't work unfortunately. I've been trying to make this work for almost 3 hours yesterday. No matter what I try I get the authentication error. I'm using the API KEY as password and it does not let me go through. I went in the settings and granted the API key all access, still does not work. I'm at lost with SendGrid atm. I love other Twilio products which I've been using for many years; but sendgrid is really malfunctioning

Comment: Is there a reason you need SMTP? Might it be easier to use the SendGrid REST API and [Node.js library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs)?

Comment: I was able to use the sandbox successfully. The reason I am trying to do with SMTP is the way my app is set up to work with Nodemailer SMTP transfer to send HTML emails from within a file stored at email.html. Now I can see we can send HTML emails with the API so I will just reiterate everything to work according to your REST API. Thanks a lot!